# PHP uploading large files, takes long and error

Tags: php, ajax

I'm uploading a large file via ajax. The upload speed is fine but when the progress bar get's to 100%, there is a long wait and then i get this error

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out) - upload.php**.

The file does appear in the destination folder but there isn't a server response.

This doesn't happen to smaller files.  It seems to take long to move_uploaded_file from the Temp folder to the destination folder.

```
  var xhr, hUploadSpeed;
        function sendFile()
        {
            document.getElementById("serverresponse").innerHTML = "";//clear previous server response

            var url = "http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme1/file-upload/upload.php";
            var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form1"));
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgress, false);//EventListener for upload progress
            xhr.addEventListener('abort', uploadAbort, false);//EventListener for abort
            xhr.addEventListener('error', uploadError, false);//EventListener for error
            xhr.addEventListener('load', uploadThrough, false);//EventListener for completed upload

            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //no longer necessary here
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("serverresponse").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }

            xhr.send(formData); //Send to server
            hUploadSpeed = setInterval(UploadSpeed, 1000); //per seconds
        }
```

Upload.php

```
//You can access the uploaded files through $_FILES 
if(isset($_FILES["file1"]))
    $target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/videos/".$_FILES["file1"]['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

echo "File uploaded successfully.";
```

This works perfectly with smaller files 50mb but when i get to files around 300mb.  It takes so long?

I have a dedicated server with this php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 1200M
post_max_size = 1200M
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = -1
max_file_uploads = 20
max_execution_time = 7200
max_input_time = 7200
max_input_vars = 1000
```

Why does it take so long?  How do i solve?

Comment: what is your php version and OS please ?

Comment: OS: CloudLinux 7.3 and PHP 5.6

Comment: Exact php version please.

Comment: It says `native PHP Version 5.6` in cpanel `ea-php56` in WHM

Answer (score 3):

There's also `memory_limit` in `php.ini` that can affect upload. `php.ini` is a server config file.

You have to increase the following values in your `php.ini` file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

and then restart the server.

Comment: I made changes to my php.ini a week ago.  Do i still have to restart the server for the changes to take place?

Comment: @mdnba50 [That depends.](//stackoverflow.com/questions/12892331/do-i-need-to-restart-apache-after-changing-the-php-ini-file)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem can be this php bug :
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73807
You php config is ok.

Fixed in 7 and 7.1 branch. Not In php 5.6 now. Maybe soon.
If you can, upgrade your app to 7.1 (performances are also more than 2 times faster), if you can't just wait php > 5.6.30

Comment: I tried to upgrade to PHP 7.1 and i get an error **missing mysql extension** because i use wordpress. How do i upgrade to PHP 5.6.30?  I don't see it on my dropdown.

Comment: in php 7+ mysql extension is gone, you must use mysqli. New wordpress version support php 7+ . Can you upgrade your WP version or use pdo/mysqli in config ? I don't know your system and php 5.6.30 don't fix this bug you need a version after 5.6.30, not realeased yet. I you can take some time to upgrade for php 7.1 is't better (faster website, etc...)

Comment: Thanks!  This solved the issue, i get a server response but when looking via FTP the file takes long to appear? I keep refreshing FTP and the file appears but  not the full size.  Every refresh and the size increases until it's full size.  Is this something i can change?  The file should be available immediately.

Comment: no you cant, upload take some time, it dont save file in on time but write bytes step by step. With better internet bandwidth it will be faster.